# logic and actions to my transporters fleet in the flow chart in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Iam trying to build a model represented as shown but the main problem is how to put my hands on transporters and can do sequence logic on them while been loaded and unloaded along the path among my flowchart sequence.[assign  queue and delay blocks to my transporter type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCsdm.jpg).
[error while doing that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9zm2.jpg).

First, i wanted to make a queue and delay before reaching loading point but when i ran the model i had an error as i tried to cast the delay and the queue to my transporter agent (forklift) and not the material item type(agent) , and when i tried to cast it to my agent (material item type) it didn't respond or see the delay or the queue and the transporter didn't stop.

After loading i want to make a second stop (delay) and queue of transporters out side it but , the model only see the delay and (loaded transporters) ran through the queue and stop in the delay block and i want to investigate the queue but the transports didn't stop in it.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite clear what you need but it sounds like you want to explore preparation flow charts as part of `Seize` and `Release` actions, see https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/resourcetaskstart.html.

With these, you can make your resources (forklifts) follow some flow chart logic before they are actually being seized by your agents. This also works with transporters afaik

Comment: i had seen that but, i didn't try it actually . can it be done on transporters or just resources?

Comment: all i want to do is to make transporters (forklifts) delay on the path after being seized while on the way to cranes to be loaded, and so one while been seiezed.

Comment: "i had seen that but, i didn't try it actually . can it be done on transporters or just resources?" --> Suggest you always first try yourself. Better learning for you :)

Comment: If your trial does not work, do return and open a new, refined issue. Some tips on writing great questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . And some special tips for AnyLogic users: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Happy to help but please make our lives as easy as possible :)

Comment: i can model it as resource from process modeling library , not a transorter. especially, i want to go back to my main flow chart as transporter loaded by my agent (material type) and want to unloded it in next stage. i just cant get it by transporter method. is it have any method??

Comment: Sorry, this gets less and less clear. Please revise from scratch and put more effort into the question :)